# Redistributing the array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I'm trying to redistribute the array of Integers.
The aim is: I have an array, let it be `{2_000_000_000, 0}`.

I need:

1. Find the max element of the array.
2. Save it to the temp variable.
3. Set the maximum element = 0.
4. Distribute the max element between rest ones, beginning from the next of max element. If the end of array is reached, I need to start from the beginning.

My code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){  //Looking for max element
    if (data.get(i) > max){             //of the array
        max = data.get(i);              //Save max element
        index = i;                      //Save the index of max element
    }
}
data.set(index, 0);              //Set max element = 0
if (index == data.size()){       //In case of end of array
    initPos = 0;                 //position is the beginning
}else {
    initPos = index + 1;         //If no the end - pos is the next
}

while (max > 0){                    //This block of code looks have
    if (initPos == data.size()){    //a small speed
        initPos = 0;
    }
    int oldVal = data.get(initPos);
    oldVal++;
    data.set(initPos, oldVal);
    max--;
    initPos++;                                 
}
```

So the question is: the code `while(max > 0)...` seems to be working slowly.

Do I need to use different structures instead of ArrayList to speed-up the distribution process?

Comment: "Distribute the max element between rest ones" - What does that mean, exactly?

Comment: Cid, thanks, edited. Should have been --max..

Comment: It works fine, but I'm trying to figure out, whether it can be working faster.. And how?

Comment: How can `index == data.size()` possibly ever be true?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, it can, as it will be incremented in the end of iteration. So if it is equal, then it will be reset to 0

Comment: @JacobG., it means that all other elements will be incrementing and the max will be decrementing until it's zero

Comment: I think you mean `if (index == data.size() - 1)` - since `data.size()` is not the index of the last element, but is one past the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping `max` times, I would calculate the amount to distribute to each other elements.

In exemple, in **pseudo code** :

```
data = { 0, 10, 42, 5, 3 };
max = 42;  // you already calculated this, so in my example, I hardcode it.
index = 2; // same than above
data[index] = 0;

amountToDistribute = max / (data.length - 1); // 42 / 4 = 10.5, but it's floored to 10 since the division is made on integers
remaining = max % (data.length - 1); // 2 remaining

loop for i = 0 to i < data.length
{
    if (i != index) // don't add to the max index
    {
        data[i] += amountToDistribute; //adding 10
    }
}
// now let's add the 2 remaining
j = index + 1;
while (remaining-- > 0)
{
    if (j >= data.length)
    {
        j = 0; //reset the iterator to 0 if the end was reached
    }
    data[j++]++; // add 1 to data[3] on first iteration, then to data[4] on the second one. It increases j too once added
}
print(data); // { 10, 20, 0, 16, 14 }
```

In my example, you have 42 to redistribute to the 4 other elements.

You can't redistribute 10.5 to each (I guess you have to use integer only)

Then you'll redistribute at least 10 (10.5 floored is 10, since the division is made on integers) to each elements.

Doing 42 modulo 4, written `42 % 4` gives you the rest of the division `42 / 4`, which is 2. The 2 remaining are redistribued the same way you wrote your first algorithm.

This can be tweaked so everything will be done in 1 loop. But it actually does 7 iterations (5 in the first loop, then 2 in the second one) instead of 42.

In that example, if you replace `{ 0, 10, 42, 5, 3 }` by `{ 0, 10, 4000000000 (4 billions), 5, 3 }` it will produce the same (adding 1 billion to each elements, but the max one) in 5 iteration instead of the 4 billions in your algorithm

Comment: Cid, thanks a lot! That makes sense, good idea! I need to think it out.

Comment: Not really, I'm a beginner in programming...  will surf the Internet

Comment: No need to use `floor` (which is a floating-point operation) as integer division produces an integer result already.

Comment: @Aleksandr I edited my answer to add more explanations.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException good catch, I edited my answer considering your comment

Comment: @Cid, thanks again. Little more clarification. Just to check whether I'm following. See if we have an array { 0, 10, 42, 5, 3 }. 1) The max is 42, index is 2. 2) Set max = 0, so { 0, 10, 0, 5, 3 }. 3) Then I need to distribute this max value between all the elements, starting from the next of max. 4) So { 0, 10, 0, 5+1, 3+1 } until the max is 0. 5) Then: {.0 + 1, 10 + 1, 0 + 1, 6 + 1, 4 + 1 }, again: { 1 + , 11 + 1, 1 + 1, 7 + 1, 5 + 1 } and so on.. while max > 0.

Comment: And after each incrementing of array element max is decrementing.